# Can Netflix Eureka server be used as a proxy between microservices environments?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

Thanks in advance everyone looking at this!
Here is what I'm trying to do:
I am developing microservices using Spring-Boot/Java with Zuul and Eureka as gateway and registry respectively. The problem I'm having is that I want to develop my new microservice locally but still be able to make calls to my other existing microservices running on a remote cluster. My thinking is that I can run Eureka locally and using its peering capability to forward failed local requests to the Eureka server that lives in the remote cluster.

My question: 
Is it possible to configure Eureka to register local services on my workstation but also forward/failover to a remote Eureka peer so that I am hitting the correct remote gateway for all my other remote microservices?

Answer (score 1):

This should be achievable by using Zones:

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#zones

In order for that to work, you'd need to have the Eureka servers see eachother as peers. The official docs for that are here:

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#spring-cloud-eureka-server-peer-awareness

You can configure your services to prefer a certain zone.

```
// Config for your production services
eureka.instance.metadataMap.zone = production
eureka.client.preferSameZoneEureka = true

// Config for your local services
eureka.instance.metadataMap.zone = local
eureka.client.preferSameZoneEureka = true
```

So any service you are running locally will be preferred but it will fall-back to the other zone if the service you call upon isn't running locally.

**Note**: It is possible this way for a "production" instance to call your local instance if there are no instances of a given service running in the production cluster but you happen to be running them locally.